# TD Amertirade API price history - json string return

Tags: python, json, api, stock, ameritrade

I have a question regarding the json string returned from the "price history" api from td ameritrade. In my python code I am able to get the candle data into a pd dataframe. I use various sites like CBOE/NYSE to get create my ticker lists, however I've noticed some of the tickers, such as AACQ, don't return any data. This could be handled if create an If loop on the "empty = true" portion of the json string. This is the generic json response summary

```
//CandleList:
{
  "candles": [
    {
      "close": 0,
      "datetime": 0,
      "high": 0,
      "low": 0,
      "open": 0,
      "volume": 0
    }
  ],
  "empty": false,
  "symbol": "string"
}
```

I get the OHLC data via

```
    # define the payload
    payload = {'apikey':client_id,
               'periodType':'day',
               'period':'10',
               'frequencyType':'minute',
               'frequency':'1',
               'needExtendedHoursData':'false'}

    # make a request content 
    time.sleep(0.501)
    content = requests.get(url = endpoint, params = payload)

    # convert it dictionary object

    data = content.json()
    #print(data)    
    hist = pd.DataFrame(data['candles'])
```

It appears to me that the json string could be made into 3 objects, 1 'candles' 2 'empty' and 3 'symbol'. Am I correct in this thinking and how might I do that. I have tried just coping my code and creating a dataframe using 'empty' but that did not work.

Comment: Please don't include sample data as images - it's actually less effort to copy/paste textual JSON data into the body of your question, and helps more to have a copy/paste-able verison of this data for others to paste into their own IDEs for testing. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to put the json text into the body but it kept giving me errors. After 15mins, I gave up and uploaded the image.

Comment: "*it kept giving me errors*" What errors in posting, exactly? Can you try again? Your question is unlikely to get much material help from others if they have to manually transcribe your JSON data.

Comment: I thought I'd just mock up a new question, but I cannot "ask a question" as my limit has been reached. Essentially it was telling me to put my code in properly. I cannot recall the exact verbiage. I tried the cntl K method and the ''' code''' method but the only portion of code was inputted properly. When I would delete the json response the red box went away, indicating I could post the question. That is why I put the png attachment instead.

Comment: I edited the question and it accepted it when I highlighted the json response and clicked the code button. Yeah...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the if and continue statement to accomplish what I wanted in my while loop

```
if df1.empty == 1:
        continue
```

but I'm still curious if I how to handle the latter two objects and even more curious about the option chain json response, which is

```
//OptionChain:
{
  "symbol": "string",
  "status": "string",
  "underlying": {
    "ask": 0,
    "askSize": 0,
    "bid": 0,
    "bidSize": 0,
    "change": 0,
    "close": 0,
    "delayed": false,
    "description": "string",
    "exchangeName": "string",
    "fiftyTwoWeekHigh": 0,
    "fiftyTwoWeekLow": 0,
    "highPrice": 0,
    "last": 0,
    "lowPrice": 0,
    "mark": 0,
    "markChange": 0,
    "markPercentChange": 0,
    "openPrice": 0,
    "percentChange": 0,
    "quoteTime": 0,
    "symbol": "string",
    "totalVolume": 0,
    "tradeTime": 0
  },
  "strategy": "'SINGLE' or 'ANALYTICAL' or 'COVERED' or 'VERTICAL' or 'CALENDAR' or 'STRANGLE' or 'STRADDLE' or 'BUTTERFLY' or 'CONDOR' or 'DIAGONAL' or 'COLLAR' or 'ROLL'",
  "interval": 0,
  "isDelayed": false,
  "isIndex": false,
  "daysToExpiration": 0,
  "interestRate": 0,
  "underlyingPrice": 0,
  "volatility": 0,
  "callExpDateMap": "object",
  "putExpDateMap": "object"
}
 //StrikePriceMap:
{}
 //Option:
{
  "putCall": "'PUT' or 'CALL'",
  "symbol": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "exchangeName": "string",
  "bidPrice": 0,
  "askPrice": 0,
  "lastPrice": 0,
  "markPrice": 0,
  "bidSize": 0,
  "askSize": 0,
  "lastSize": 0,
  "highPrice": 0,
  "lowPrice": 0,
  "openPrice": 0,
  "closePrice": 0,
  "totalVolume": 0,
  "quoteTimeInLong": 0,
  "tradeTimeInLong": 0,
  "netChange": 0,
  "volatility": 0,
  "delta": 0,
  "gamma": 0,
  "theta": 0,
  "vega": 0,
  "rho": 0,
  "timeValue": 0,
  "openInterest": 0,
  "isInTheMoney": false,
  "theoreticalOptionValue": 0,
  "theoreticalVolatility": 0,
  "isMini": false,
  "isNonStandard": false,
  "optionDeliverablesList": [
    {
      "symbol": "string",
      "assetType": "string",
      "deliverableUnits": "string",
      "currencyType": "string"
    }
  ],
  "strikePrice": 0,
  "expirationDate": "string",
  "expirationType": "string",
  "multiplier": 0,
  "settlementType": "string",
  "deliverableNote": "string",
  "isIndexOption": false,
  "percentChange": 0,
  "markChange": 0,
  "markPercentChange": 0
}
 //Underlying:
{
  "ask": 0,
  "askSize": 0,
  "bid": 0,
  "bidSize": 0,
  "change": 0,
  "close": 0,
  "delayed": false,
  "description": "string",
  "exchangeName": "'IND' or 'ASE' or 'NYS' or 'NAS' or 'NAP' or 'PAC' or 'OPR' or 'BATS'",
  "fiftyTwoWeekHigh": 0,
  "fiftyTwoWeekLow": 0,
  "highPrice": 0,
  "last": 0,
  "lowPrice": 0,
  "mark": 0,
  "markChange": 0,
  "markPercentChange": 0,
  "openPrice": 0,
  "percentChange": 0,
  "quoteTime": 0,
  "symbol": "string",
  "totalVolume": 0,
  "tradeTime": 0
}
 //ExpirationDate:
{
  "date": "string"
}
 //OptionDeliverables:
{
  "symbol": "string",
  "assetType": "string",
  "deliverableUnits": "string",
  "currencyType": "string"
}
```

I have been trying to figure out how to bring this data into my database.

Comment: I see you're new to our communities, let me offer you some helpful tips. First, the question should be clear and concise. Your question relates specifically to the TD Ameritrade API, yet you haven't included [ameritrade] tag in your question. Furthermore, since your answer didn't solve the problem, you should have just edited the question itself rather than post an answer. And lastly, I recommend you turn the title of the post to question form (a short and clear question that describes the essence of your problem).